# raspberry pi python-tesseract install

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, tesseract, python-tesseract

A few months ago I created a project that uses the python-tesseract library on the raspberry pi. Since then I reinstalled rasbpian, and now I would like to reinstall the python-tesseract libary. The problem I'm having is that the library doesn't install anymore on the raspberry pi. The raspberry-pi was never officially supported, but it could be installed. The installition process I used a few months ago, doesn't work anymore and I tried everything I could find but nothing worked. Did anyone lately install python-tesseract on the pi? If yes, how?

python 2.7

Raspbian fully up-to-date (including firmware)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Raspberry Pi specific issues. I think it is better suited for the specific Raspberry Pi site in Stack Exchange: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thnx for the tip! I will post my question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that works! For anyone with the same problem I posted my solution here:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22059/raspberry-pi-python-tesseract-install/22081#22081